# Custom Style Sheet, Move TopNavBar?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, style.css

Long-time SP Admin, nuts & bolts kinda guy; n00b sp designer: The company which i have worked with for 3 years as a Sys Admin, looking after everything a sys admin would, including SharePoint. I am the back-end administrator whom initially deployed it and i build custom lists and workflows etc. The company is growing and so is the use of SharePoint so-much-so that i have moved in to a role that is focusing 100% on SharePoint.

wonder if you guys could help me out. I want to override the masterpage with a custom style sheet to modify some items. I have already copied the default masterpage, renamed it and added in the override file. I have managed to so far modify some basic items, but what i am really struggling with is the location of the top navigation bar. I want to position it BELOW the site logo, along with the search bar.. any ideas on what coding i need to do this?

[image: My Current Site]

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to do this just with css, but that isn't really the right tool.

Since you have access to the master page and can edit it, I think you'll get a lot further by moving the html/markup around. I'm not sure which version of SP you've got, but we have SP2013 on-prem. Your image looks like this is based on Seattle?

Open the masterpage in an html editor, we use Dreamweaver, but it could be anything or even just Notepad, but it it is easier to see with something that does color coding of the html parts.

Any ways, look for the logo and navigation snippets. They will be marked with

```
<!--CS: Start Site Logo Snippet-->
```

and (I think...)

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline" runat="server">-->
```

Those will be wrapped in various  elements. You can then take the entire contents of a div and move it to a different div or even add new divs to the layout. Do you have experience with html?

Comment: Hi! - Thanks for the reply! - i have little html/css coding experience but am capable enough to know where to find what i need in terms of master-page, display pages etc.. etc.. and can mess around with it until it works. A fellow SharePoint enthusiast told me that its best practice to override the styles using an override insert in to the masterpage and not actually make changes to the masterpage itself.. but i guess thats just his opinion.

Comment: Overall, I would agree for stuff like font size, spacing, some alignment, and so on. Something like this is a major change to the structure of the layout and not just the styling. Maybe if you were using flexbox or css-grid (once it becomes available). In my experience, I think you would be fighting with it for a long time to get it how you want if you went with pure css.